# How to handle multiple solidity versions

Tags: solidity

I need Solidity version manager to manage multiple version of `solc` installed globally. 
Is there a `rbenv`, `nvm`, `pyenv` tool for solidity?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the version of Solidity at the top of each file.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.12;

...
```

If you have the latest version of Solidity it will handle compilation of old versions. More about the pragma [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/layout-of-source-files.html#version-pragma).

Answer (score 1):

This is actually covered in the [`solc-js` documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#using-a-legacy-version).

Comment: won't work. I need to be able to switch versions using CLI binary

Comment: Why not write a wrapper for the cli binary that uses the node interface?

Comment: I suppose this is what I have to do

Comment: If this is something that there's big demand for, I might work on something for it.  I've been (slowly) building a set of build tools for contracts over the past couple weeks anyway, so this might be a useful addition.

Comment: I will contribute to it

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but since OP ask for solidity equivalent of `nvm`, I would like to point out to [`svm`](https://github.com/web3j/svm) for solidity compiler version management for the sake of reference.